# How do I set a belongs_to association to Nil when the associated object is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

If I destroy a Brand object, the child Cars still have their `car.brand_id` attributes set to the destroyed `brand.id`.

How can I null out the `car.brand_id` of the child Cars when destroying the parent Brand?

I thought the ActiveRecord relationship would handle this, and prevent orphaned objects.

I don't want to `dependent: :destroy` the Cars, but just want to have their `car.brand_id` set to nil.

I don't want to have to write an `after_commit` for this, I want Rails magic to handle this.  Or less ideally a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about `dependent: :nullify` on `Brand` model?

4.3.2.4 :dependent

Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed:

...

`:nullify` causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.

...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference